Python Application on Kamatera Server Keeps Dying and Hanging
I'm running a Python application on a Kamatera server with FreeBSD 14, using supervisord for automatic restarts.
The supervisord config is as follows:
[program:reactivebb]
command=poetry run python3.11 /home/rulo/reactive-bb-build/start.py
autorestart=true
startsecs=60
startretries=3

[supervisord]

The application's main script is:
    import json
    import uvicorn
    import asyncio
    from api.read_config import config_to_environ
    from starlette.config import environ
    from typing import Any
    
    async def main() -> None:
        await config_to_environ()
        server_conf: dict[str, Any] = json.loads(environ["SERVER"])
        environment: str = environ["ENVIRON"]
        port: int = int(server_conf["port"])
        socket_name: str = server_conf["sockName"]
    
        from api.app import get_main_app
        main_app = get_main_app()
    
        if environment == "development":
            config = uvicorn.Config(
                main_app, port=port, log_level="info", log_config="log.json"
            )
        else:
            config = uvicorn.Config(
                main_app, uds=socket_name, log_level="info", log_config="log.json"
            )
    
        server: uvicorn.Server = uvicorn.Server(config)
        await server.serve()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        asyncio.run(main())

The application runs via a socket in production.
Despite this setup, the process dies after a few hours, causing the server to hang and require a reboot.
Is this issue related to Kamatera, or is there something wrong with my application setup?
